# 301 redirect (mod rewrite) a whole folder and all files with the get parameters

Tags: mod-rewrite, redirect, rewrite, 301-redirect

I want to redirect all urls starting with www.site.com/online/ to www.site.com

some examples of the files I'm trying to redirect are ...

```
www.site.com/online/folder1/folder2/folder3/?gdt=wbgMfFt9PVUKEwjiparBqM-kAhUMdoYKHW5GKa0QAhgBIAQw-PuCATgeUPj7ggFQpPmYD1CGra8PUIvr_xNQuOv_E1DU6IQbUIq23B5QsuXZIFD5uqqnAVCDrYrIAVCgy5HZAQ&slt=8&slr=5&lpt=2
```

my current condition is very simple and it is doing everything except for removing the parameter in the url.

```
RewriteRule ^online/(.*)  http://www.site.com [R=301,L]
```

right now this rule will redirect

```
www.site.com/online/folder1/folder2/folder3/?randomgetparameter=blablabla
```

to

```
www.site.com/?randomgetparameter=blablabla
```

instead of redirecting to

```
www.site.com
```

Answer (score 1):

From [apache docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html):

```
Modifying the Query String

By default, the query string is passed through unchanged. You can, however,
create URLs in the substitution string containing a query string part.
Simply use a question mark inside the substitution string to indicate that
the following text should be re-injected into the query string. When you want
to erase an existing query string, end the substitution string with just a
question mark. To combine new and old query strings, use the [QSA] flag.
```

So -- try: RewriteRule ^online/(.*)  http://www.site.com/? [R=301,L]